# How can I submit localStorage data to Django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have data in localStorage,and I want to submit it along with userid to Django through POST request. How do I make this work?

1) Send Ajax request: it requires csrf token and I can't make it valid.

```
  function submitData() {
  // send result to server
    var data = localStorage.getItem("groups");
    var userid = {{user.userid}};
    console.log(data);

    $.ajax({
      url:"/interface/submit/",
      type:"POST",
      data: { group:data,
              userid:userid,
              csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},
      success:function() {
        alert("Submitted succeffully");
        window.location = "/interface/";
      }
    })
  }
```

2) Use Django forms: for now i can only grab information from the field, not localStorage.

```
  <form action="/interface/submit/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

Error when using the 1st approach:

Request information

```
GET
Variable    Value
csrfmiddlewaretoken 
u'{{ csrf_token }}'
group   
u'371,197,220,306,213,328,399,373,283,end,371,197,220,306,213,328,399,373,283,end,371,197,220,end,'
POST
No POST data
FILES
No FILES data
COOKIES
Variable    Value
csrftoken   
'F8jc4jObrxI2bQ6Y3CgCiuf6MTOpf2Uo'
sessionid   
'8uvrhe9yytpam38h5xb4tnvz8ijiui4p'
```

Comment: What error do you encounter with the first method?

Comment: What is the question? The question is what is the best way? The best way is the one that fit your requirements. So what are your requirements^

Comment: Regarding 1) is your template rendering a form with {% csrf_token %} where you use your ajax code? If not, Django won't send a new csrf cookie with the response. [edit] removed link and text and moved to answer for better readability

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 1) is your template rendering a form with {% csrf_token %} where you use your ajax code? If not, Django won't send a new csrf cookie with the response.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax

> If your view is not rendering a template containing the csrf_token template tag, Django might not set the CSRF token cookie. This is common in cases where forms are dynamically added to the page. To address this case, Django provides a view decorator which forces setting of the cookie: ensure_csrf_cookie().

Comment: Thanks. It does: "csrfmiddlewaretoken: 'F8jc4jObrxI2bQ6Y3CgCiuf6MTOpf2Uo'}," ( when I check the source of the page).